# Multiple device push

Tags: android, ios, firebase, websocket, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement an push application which should work on iOS, Android and in the browser.

Do I need to implement one solution for iOS and Android (FCM) and one for the browser (WebSockets)? Or is it possible to e.g. push with WebSockets to all devices?

FCM supports Chrome as a client. But I don't want to force users to use Chrome as their browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WebSockets**

If you are using Websockets for push in Android and iOS, you will receive the push only if the application is open. That means only if you establish the connection successfully.

**FCM**

If your client registration is successful and you have an FCM registration id even if the app is not in foreground you will receive the push.

So I suggest to use FCM for Android and iOS.

Comment: iOS has APN - so does FCM just implement the APN part?

Comment: FCM will work for both android and ios , its a replacement for GCM and  APN

Comment: and there is no way to implement a push notification on my own (e.g. a WebSocket connection to the push service on the device)?

Comment: In that case you should create listener that that will work even when the app is closed. I think that can be achieved  through a web socket and a service that will ping back to the web socket to make it live.

Comment: But using service in that manner will make great impact in the performance of the app regarding CPU and battery life.

Comment: fcm or gcm have a common point in android for all application and once a push received it will give that to the corresponding application.

Comment: ok, then FCM should be the best solution (I can still send few data via FCM and then send the remaining when opening the app)

thank you!